# Broken Links within Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: document

I have a huge number of documents uploaded to the document library. These are the word and excel documents. We have some links within the documents refering to the old URL of the sharepoint website. How do I updated these URLs which are within the documents of Sharepoint document library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update [SPFieldUrlValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue.aspx) value for each of your document.

Here's example,

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                    {
                        Object rawValue = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.URL];
                        SPFieldUrlValue typedValue = new SPFieldUrlValue(rawValue.ToString());
```

For more information check these links out,

[Update Document meta data in SharePoint library using Event Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109527/update-document-meta-data-in-sharepoint-library-using-event-receiver)

[SPFieldUrlValue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue.aspx)

[How to programmatically create document set, add or move files, GetDocumentSetById](http://www.howtosp.com/blog/2010/12/06/programmatically-create-document-set-add-or-move-files-getdocumentsetbyid/)